# .slice() method in Javascript not copy by value

Tags: javascript

Okay so I am trying to make an AI for a game called notakto. That much isn't relevant however, in order to make the search algorithm that I do I need to duplicate array. So I have a global array called `board` which looks like this `[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]` where all of the 0s are different numbers.
To copy this I have the following line. `var newboard=board.slice()`. Problem is when I run a line of code like `newboard[0][0]=1` it changes also acts as if I have run the following `board[0][0]=1`.

Comment: You have to make a copy of each of the nested arrays too.

Comment: `.slice()` makes a copy of the array it's given, but it doesn't work recursively.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can get a deep copy with `$.extend`.

Comment: There's always the old `var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));` trick

Comment: `slice()` make only shallow copy. See jQuery.[extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: You have multiple instances of a thing, each with the same properties and functions?  Sounds like a job for [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy your array, but the inner arrays are not copied. This is a litte bit hacky but it works:

```
var newboard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
```

In this context it will work, but if your object has any functions these are lost through stringify. Moreover it could make some trouble with Data objects which are stored inside the object.

Comment: You might want to explain the limitations of this approach so that others are not blindly copying this.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for your advice. I edited the post to mention some limitations I know.

Answer (score 0):

It's because nested arrays are shallow-copied by reference. You can use a recursive function like this to deep-copy a multidimensional array such as the one you have above, making sure that each nested array is copied by value:

```js
function copyMultidimensionalArray(array) {
    var r = array.slice(0);
    for (var i = 0, l = r.length; i < l; ++i) {
         if (Array.isArray(r[i])) {
             r[i] = copyMultidimensionalArray(r[i]);
         }
    }
    return r;
}

/* example */

var board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    anotherBoard = copyMultidimensionalArray(board);

anotherBoard[0][0] = 99;

document.write([
    "board[0][0] ===",
    board[0][0],
    "&& anotherBoard[0][0] ===",
    anotherBoard[0][0]
].join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is always reference based. if you want to make a duplicate copy, please do deep object copy instead of sallow copy. 
In angular, `angular.copy()` will perform deep copy.

`var newboard=angular.copy(board.slice());`

Comment: There is no angular tag on this question.

Comment: that is for just example to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `board.map(function(cv){ return cv.slice();})` to copy the board:

```js
var board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

var board2 = board.map(function(cv){ return cv.slice();});

board2[0][0] = 1;

console.log(board);
console.log(board2);
```